# How to print out whole matrix from unitary simulator

Tags: qiskit

On Jupyter Notebook, I had simulated eight qubits quantum's circuit with Unitary_simulator. And then, I would like to print out the whole matrix, but what I get is [matrix from unitary simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtBHu.png). 
The code that I used is:

```py
unitary = job.result().get_unitary(cir)
print("Circuit unitary:\n", unitary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is a 2D array, so you could print it as

```py
for row in unitary:
    print(row)
```